# What is the gender distribution of nouns in the German language?

Tags: gender

I want a rough estimate of the percentage of nouns that belongs to each gender category

Comment: While it is not really addressed in the answers, I have a hunch the rough estimate will vary considerably depending on which set of "systematically constructable" nouns you include. For instance, by including verbs converted to nouns (das Sein, das Wollen, das Gehören, ...) and/or diminutives (das Geschlechtchen, das Verteilungchen, das Substantivchen, ...), the percentage of neuter nouns would rise drastically.

Comment: Do you want to count each word exactly once or do you want to count every occurance?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to a footnote in [this study (Warning: PDF file)](http://www.wjh.harvard.edu/~caram/PDFs/2003_Schiller_Caramazza.pdf):

> The distribution of the three genders in German is as follows. There
>   are 4164 monomorphemic nouns listed in the CELEX database (Baayen,
>   Piepenbrock, & Gulikers, 1995). Fifty-one of these have multiple
>   genders (e.g., der See [the lake]vs. die See [the sea]). Of the
>   remaining 4113 entries, 1758(42.74%) have masculine gender, 1567
>   (38.10%) have feminine gender, and 788 (19.16%) are neuter

which means you can roughly say that 40% are feminine, 40% are masculine and 20% are neuter

Comment: While the rough estimate may be there, in the context of this question, it does not appear adequate to exclude nouns that work with several genders - least of all if these could be described as "two distinct nouns that match neither in gender nor in meaning, but that happen to be written and spoken the same", as the mentioned pair "der See" + "die See".

Comment: @O.R.Mapper The fact that there are only 51 of them in the database means it's adequate to ignore them (and every argument about them).

Answer (score 10):

I have been self-studying German by reading the German press for the past 27 months. In the process, I'm writing out *almost all* unfamiliar German words, including nouns. As of May 10, 2016, there are 23.000 words in my German word list. Today I counted the nouns in my word list and looked into their gender distribution.

It turned out that my list contains around 10.375 nouns, of which about 44% are feminine, 36% are masculine, and 19% are neutral. 47 nouns can be used with any of two genders (e.g. der/das Kalkül or die/das Soja) and Joghurt can be used with either of the three genders: der/die/das Joghurt

Comment: My hat is off to you. That's dedication!

Comment: Although for the aim of this question it's an irrelevant percentage: *Kalkül* cannot be used with two genders. It's two words: *Kalkül* in *der Funktionalkalkül* is not the same word as in *ins Kalkül* *ziehen*. So is *Moment*: neutrum is the physical quantity, masculine it's *Augenblick.* Or even *Partikel*.

Comment: If you only write out uncommon nouns, I would almost expect a skewed result towards feminine since many of the nominalised adjectives have feminine genus and they tend to be ‘unusual’.

Comment: @Jan's is an excellent catch

Answer (score 5):

According to the duden.de, %46: die; %34: der; %20: das
Two genders existence is 1.3%.

See: https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Die-Verteilung-der-Artikel-Genusangabe-im-Rechtschreibduden

Answer (score 3):

Here are some statistics from Canoo.net

[Link](http://canoonet.eu/blog/2007/12/28/128/)

weibliche Nomen: ca. 68’000 = 40%

männliche Nomen: ca. 52’000 = 31%

sächliche Nomen: ca. 49’000 = 29%

Answer (score 2):

An interesting addendum (or extension to all words) to [idober](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/3835/447)'s answer:

If you assume that **none of these three categories is favoured**, and you [look at the distribution](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=der,die,%20das&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3) of *articles* used, you get a similar result:

> masculine 47%
>   feminine 40%
>   neuter 13%

Now this is very rough, because you only take into account "der,die,das" while "die" is used in more feminine inflections than "der". There are more inaccuracies, but the rough picture is a nice estimate, I believe.

However, I find it interesting that you get a result that is very close to the study based on CELEX data.

Comment: Won't counting only articles get you misleading data, because *die* is used for all plurals, *der* can be masculine nominative or feminine dative/genitive, and *dem* and *des* can be either masculine or neuter?

Comment: Yes. I even pointed this out in my answer! However, it's an indicator for what you can expect. It is to be taken with extreme caution, though. I think this leads to the question: "What's the distribution of cases?"

Comment: Distribution of cases would be interesting. I'd expect mostly nominative & accusative, a smaller amount of dative, and very little genitive (especially in spoken or informal contexts).

Comment: I understand the question as asking for the number of masculine words in the dictionary - not the number of words used in texts. They don't need to match. Some words are used often, some are used rarely.

Comment: @userunknown: Surely they are. However, my assumption was, that a word wouldn't be used more often simply because it is masculine (I even highlighted this *assumption*). Under this assumption, the number of uses in texts should match the number of words in the dictionary.

Comment: I think you're confusing causation and correlation here. I can assume that the usage of nouns is correlated with the gender, but not caused by it.

Comment: @userunknown: No I am not. However, my choice of words might have been a bit ambiguous there :)