# How many masculine, feminine, neuter and plural nouns are there in German language?

Tags: gender, dictionary

In german class, a discussion came up, and in it somebody asked how many der, die, das, and die (plural) words are there?

I have looked into other websites but have not found anything.

Comment: Exactly those four IMO. Can you be a bit more precise what you're looking for (add some example sentences/usages maybe).

Comment: I want to know the number of masculine, feminine, and neuter nouns.

Comment: This is a question that cannot really be answered. Languages are like living organisms. They develop permanently. There are new words emerging everyday. - Counter question of similar quality: how many words does the English language have?

Comment: @Stiffy2000 There are thousands of masculine, feminine and neuter nouns, and new ones can be invented from combinations or even as completely new words never heard before, It's actually hard to tell.

Comment: Something rough (like percent) will do.

Comment: @Stiffy2000 What about writing a query to count these from an online dictionary's API? I'am afraid that no one here is likely to give any efforts in doing such for you.

Comment: The answer: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3834/what-is-the-gender-distribution-of-nouns-in-the-german-language

Comment: @User That would well apply for marking that question as a duplicate.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ  Yeah, of course. I don't have enough reputation to mark it as duplicate :)

Comment: @User You have enough reputation to flag it as such. That would go just fine.

Comment: If you are asking about the percentages, the Q/A linked above contains the information and your post is a duplicate. If you are asking about absolute numbers, see the other comments above.